# Update List from another List with Matching values using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, collections

I wish to update values in a List when I query context from another source

I can FIND the matches with 2 different styles of queries

```
var r = from aa in context.Persons.GetItems()
        join bb in findPersonViewModel.findPersonResultsViewModel on aa.PersonId equals bb.PersonID
        select aa;
```

OR

```
var results = context.Persons.GetItems().Where(ax => findPersonViewModel.findPersonResultsViewModel.Any(b => ax.PersonId == b.PersonID));
```

For Simplicity sake, I shortened the models

```
public class FindPersonResultsViewModel
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public bool ExistInContactManager { get; set; }
    public bool ActionType { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
     public int PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

**Goal:  If the PersonID matches, then update the FindPersonResultsViewModel to have both `ExistinContactManager` and `ActionType` to be `True`**

Here is a sample of the data for a visual

```
var findPersonResultsViewModel = new List<FindPersonResultsViewModel>()
    { new FindPersonResultsViewModel { PersonID = 2, ActionType = false, ExistInContactManager = false },
      new FindPersonResultsViewModel { PersonID = 3, ActionType = false, ExistInContactManager = false },
      new FindPersonResultsViewModel { PersonID = 4, ActionType = false, ExistInContactManager = false },
      new FindPersonResultsViewModel { PersonID = 5, ActionType = false, ExistInContactManager = false },
      new FindPersonResultsViewModel { PersonID = 6, ActionType = false, ExistInContactManager = false },
    };



var personModel = new List<PersonViewModel>()
    { new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 2 },
      new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 6 },
      new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 8 },
      new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 9 },
      new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 12 },
      new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 22 },
      new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 32 },
      new PersonViewModel { PersonID = 42 },
    };
```

Comment: Upvote for the included data, classes and effort

Comment: Linq is for querying (filtering, joining, etc., with the end goal of selecting something), not updating

Comment: @RufusL   Yes,  However I had inserted.  Gotcha.   If I now want to update records and essentially I have 2 list,  I found the records ,  how can I update?  some type of loop ?   example ?

Comment: @RufusL, isn't that dependent on the use? What's stopping me from continuing the pipeline that finds the matches and `Select` (map), and save, the changes?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils  That is what I thought...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I don't follow, can you show an example? How do you follow a `.Select` with something that modifies items in the collection? Or maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: @ChadJacobs Yes, a loop is normally a good way to iterate over a collection if you want to modify the items.

Comment: @RufusL, that'd be hard in a comment but say `m` represents the matches from their query. Now, `m.Select(makeThemTruthy);` is all the matches mutated as desired. Now, your comment comes into play. If it's a basic collection, you would not have mutated/"updated" the original collection; it's a new collection. If it's a `DbContext`, that's different. But in any case, you still have the updated collection. Now, save it as needed.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Oh, when you said "continue the pipeline" I thought you meant something in a fluent way, where there would be something after the `.Select` that modified the items you just selected (in the same statement). I don't believe that's possible in Linq (but I may be wrong). I mean, you can do `.ToList().ForEach(x => x.SomeProperty = newValue)`, but that's cheating. :)

Comment: @RufusL, possibly. The method/fluent syntax in their example is easier to see how it's possible though you could wrap the linq query statement in parens and achieve the same thing. So after the `Where(...)` clause (which is just `Filter`) you have a collection of matches. That result is enumerable/queryable itself. Are we on the same topic :) ?

Comment: @RufusL, actually, that doesn't work to mutate. That is a terminal function meaning it doesn't return anything so you would have achieved nothing unless the thing you're mutating lives outside the pipeline. But yes, that's cheating and stinky too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking... You could just use `Contains` and a `foreach`

```
var ids = personModel.Select(x => x.PersonID);

var results = findPersonResultsViewModel.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.PersonID));

foreach (var item in results)
{
   item.ActionType = true;       
   item.ExistInContactManager = true
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Or you could save your self a round trip by just using a `Join`, and update using a `foreach`

```
var results =
   from pr in findPersonResultsViewModel
   join p in personModel on pr.PersonID equals p.PersonID
   select pr;

foreach (var item in results)
{
   item.ActionType = true;
   item.ExistInContactManager = true;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

**Output**

```
PersonID : 2, ActionType :True, ExistInContactManager :True
PersonID : 3, ActionType :False, ExistInContactManager :False
PersonID : 4, ActionType :False, ExistInContactManager :False
PersonID : 5, ActionType :False, ExistInContactManager :False
PersonID : 6, ActionType :True, ExistInContactManager :True
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/zLJ9fx)

Comment: The only trouble I now have is that my original model I was hoping to still use for displaying on a UI grid (all data in findPersonResultsViewModel)  and now I have a separate result that is isolated.    You wouldn't have known this as I didn't talk about it... i'm not doing SaveChanges in this scenario.   Thoughts?

Comment: @ChadJacobs are both lists in memory ?

Comment: So essentially should I update the   `findPersonViewModel.findPersonResultsViewModel` in a foreach  ?

Comment: no,  the `context.Persons.GetItems()` is not in memory

Comment: @ChadJacobs Yeah so basically you might want to use the first one (if i am understanding you) load the Persons.GetItems(), get the ids, do a Contains on the list of FindPersonResultsViewModels then update with a foreach.

Comment: Worked great btw.